# How to change the area and the scale of a geo tiff files in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, geolocation, geotiff, saving-data

I possess two TIFF geo-files with different sizes and scales. The objective is to convert the geo-files to the same area and scale. Specifically, this means aligning the areas with each other first and then adjusting the resolution to the same scale.

I have problems with saving with the correct transform. This is my function for cropping

import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import Window

def crop_geotiff(input_file, output_file, crop_source_file):
# Open het bron GeoTIFF-bestand om de uitsnijparameters te verkrijgen
with rasterio.open(crop_source_file) as crop_src:
# Coördinaten van het uit te snijden gebied instellen (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = crop_src.bounds

```
    # Bepaal de vensterparameters op basis van de broncoördinaten
    window = Window.from_slices(slice(ymin, ymax), slice(xmin, xmax))

    # Open het GeoTIFF-bestand dat moet worden uitgesneden
    with rasterio.open(input_file) as src:
        # Lees de gegevens binnen het opgegeven venster
        cropped_data = src.read(window=window)

        # Update de transform en resolutie voor het uitgesneden gebied
        new_transform = src.window_transform(window)

        # Schrijf de uitgesneden gegevens naar een nieuw bestand
        with rasterio.open(
            output_file,
            'w',
            driver='GTiff',
            count=src.count,
            dtype=src.dtypes[0],
            crs=src.crs,
            transform=new_transform,
            width=window.width,
            height=window.height,
        ) as dst:
            dst.write(cropped_data)
```

## Uitvoeren van de uitsnijding

crop_geotiff(input_file, output_file_cropped, crop_source_file)